# I can't UPDATE database mysqli PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

This is todolist project. This project is about login-> addtask ->submit and store it in database and now I have problem about edit task

Why update query isn't updating data in my database?

Connect database and select is working.

This is html homepage

> home.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
require ('dbms.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header('Location: index.php?login=noLOGIN');
    exit();
}

?>

<h2>Hello <?php  echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </h2>
<h2>Add Todolist</h2>
<form action="conadd.php" method="post">

  <label>header: </label> <br>
   <input type="text"  name="header" > <br>
    <label>detail: </label>  <br>

    <textarea  type="text" name="detail" ></textarea> <br>
    <label>priority:</label><br> 
    <input type="text"   name="type" ><br>

    <input type="date"  name ="time" ><br>

    <button type="submit" name="addtask"> submit</button>
</form>
<hr>

  <?php
$sql_incom = "SELECT * FROM tb_note WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";
$result_incom = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_incom);

if($result_incom->num_rows >0 ){

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_incom)){

           echo "<li>";
           echo '<input type="checkbox"><label>'.$row["header"].'</label><input type="text">';
           echo  $row["detail"];
           echo $row["type"];
            echo $row["time"];
            ?>
            <a href="editpage.php?note_id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> Edit</a>
            <?php
           echo "</li>";
          }
        }
          ?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
```

this is edit html

> editpage.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
require ('dbms.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header('Location: index.php?login=noLOGIN');
    exit();
}
?>
<h2>Hello <?php  echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </h2>
<h2>Edit Todolist</h2>

<?php
$sql_incom = "SELECT * FROM tb_note WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  id = '".$_GET['note_id']."' ";
$result_incom = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_incom);
if($result_incom->num_rows >0 ){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_incom)){          
var_dump($row);
    echo '<form action="conedit.php" method="post">';
    echo '<label>header: </label> <br>';
    echo  '<input type="text"  name="header" value="'.$row["header"].'"> <br>';
    echo '<label>detail: </label>  <br>';
    echo  '<textarea type="text" name="detail" cols="66" rows="10">'.$row["detail"].'</textarea> <br>' ;
    echo '<label>priority:</label><br>';
    echo '<input type="text"  name="type" value="'.$row["type"].'"><br>';
    echo '<input type="date"  name ="time" value="'.$row["time"].'"><br>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="note_id" value="'.$row["id"].'">'; 

    echo '<button type="edit" name="editbtn"> submit</button>';
echo '</form> ';

          }
        }
?>
```

this is update sql

> conedit.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
include ('dbms.php');

if(isset($_POST['editbtn'])){

    $id = $_POST['note_id'];
    $header =$_POST['header'];
    $detail =$_POST['detail'];
    $time =  $_POST['time'];
    $type =  $_POST['type'];

    if($header =="" || $detail == "" || $type =="" ){
      header('Location: home.php?note=failtime');

            exit();
        }
        //$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $sql_comm = 
        "UPDATE tb_note
         SET header = '$header',
         detail ='$detail',
         time = '$time',
         type = '$type',
          WHERE id = '$id';";

    if ($conn->query($sql_comm) === TRUE) {

        header('location: home.php?add=true');
          exit();
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error ".$sql_comm ;
        }
    }
?>
```

this is error code but i think sql is correct.

```
Connected successfullyError UPDATE tb_note SET header = 'test3', detail ='go bkk', time = '2017-10-20', type = '1', WHERE id = '8';
```

Comment: Do you getting any error...?

Comment: What exact error message are you getting and at what stage in your code? It's best to be specific as possible rather than providing your entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view ,as error says remove the `,` before `where` in the `update query` that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You did not concatenated your parameters in your update request, I think you should change this first. You should also check about "prepare", because here you expose yourself to sql injections. Link [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php).

```
    $sql_comm = 
    "UPDATE tb_note
     SET header = :header,
     detail = :detail,
     time = :time,
     type = :type,
      WHERE id = :id;";

    $conn->prepare($sql_comm, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY))
    $conn->execute(
         array(
           ':header' => $header,
           ':detail' => $detail,
           ':time' => $time,
           ':type' => $type,
           ':id' => $id
         )
    );
```